# Only Accepting 2 as a number and giving wrong output of odd or even

Tags: java, switch-statement, new-operator

Good morning,
I'm trying to learn somethings on my own. As I'm overloaded for assignments as it is. This is just a small practice program I was working on. I get it to this point however, I'm unsure of what is happening. 
When given a number other than 2 it says "Please input a valid number, Thank you"
When given 2 it says "The Number is not even so there are Remainders"
I'm unsure why I'm getting this. Why is it not accepting other numbers and why is it saying 2 isn't even?
Any help on what I'm interpreting wrong would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1
{

    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int num = keyboard.nextInt();

    public static int isEven()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        switch (num)
        {

          case 1:
              if (num % 2 == 0)
              System.out.println("The Number is Even no Remainders");
              break;
          case 2:
              if (num % 2 != 0);
              System.out.println("The Number is not even so there are Remainders");
              break;
          default:
             System.out.println("Please input a valid number, Thank you.");

        }//switch
        /*pull number from user
        //store in num
        //if even print message num is even
        //else print message not an even number
         * This is the remainder of my psuedcode notes to remind me how my
         * mind was flowing
         */
        return num;

    } //isEven

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Assignment1.isEven();

    }//main
}//public class assignment one
```

Comment: What is your understanding of how a `switch` works? What do `case` do? What does `default` do?

Comment: You should probably read about how the switch-case statement works. You currently only have cases for the numbers 1 and 2 and for every other number you output that a valid number must be input (the default case). I'm not sure why you need that switch statement at all. It seems pretty pointless and you would just need an if-else-if-else statement.

Comment: Yes, your case statement right now only evaluates the numbers 1 and 2. Any other number is evaluated by the default statement, so that is why you would receive that output

Comment: And what are the cases you presented? What do they catch?

Comment: I will re-read the documentation for the switch-case statements. I thought I was evaluting all input that it would get. Meaning a even number, an odd number, and not a number.
For why I was using the switch-case, the practice I was trying to do suggested trying a switch-case instead of a if-else. I did an if-else yesterday and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: It does evaluate all input, it just directs to the appropriate case. You've got a case for 1 and a case for 2, the rest goes to default.

Comment: @JackD: `case 1` <- This case get executed if num is 1, `case 2` gets executed if  num is 2 and everything else goes to default case. If you were to add `case 2351` then that case would be executed if the number  entered is 2351. But since making a case for every possible number entered is not really a solution you should be able to tell that making a switch on the numb er entered is not the way to go here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  &OH GOD SPIDERS I guess my thinking was wrong here. I was thinking Case 1 would evaluate if there were remainders greater than zero it would go to case 2, then case two would check it and if there were reminders it would say odd, and if it couldn't get either it would drop to default. Ok so I just need to review the switch-case statements then. I haven't done any of this in a long time. Thank you both

Comment: @JackD in this situation you could use an if-else condition which makes more sense. With the switch statement, you can only evaluate the conditions within your case or default statement. Making a case for every number is cumbersome obviously. An if else condition could simply be deployed within the method, and the method could take an integer value as an argument. If it can be divided by zero it will return a particular statement and if it cannot be divided by zero it will return a particular statement

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo  Thank you, yes I see that it does now. I was just trying to do the other practice form of the the program. And I apparently need to review the documentation for switch-case. But I didn't have any issues with the if-else version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for switch-case is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) .

And now try this, I added some comment to lines. **Read those carefully**.

```
public class Assignment1 {

    public static int isEven() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = keyboard.nextInt();

        num = num % 2; // divide by 2 and get a remainder.
        switch (num) {
            case 0: //case 0 means if number equal to zero
                System.out.println("The Number is Even no Remainders");
                break;
            case 1: // case 1 means if number equal to one
                System.out.println("The Number is not even so there are Remainders");
                break;
            default: // if no one match if not a valid.
                System.out.println("Please input a valid number, Thank you.");

        }//switch
        /*pull number from user
        //store in num
        //if even print message num is even
        //else print message not an even number
         * This is the remainder of my psuedcode notes to remind me how my
         * mind was flowing
         */
        return num;

    } //isEven

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Assignment1.isEven();

    }//
}
```

Comment: The `default` case is dead code since `num % 2` will always be handled by `case 0` or `case 1`.

Comment: yes, you are right. i didnot removed for understanding of default case.